# What is the "+1" in (log2 N +1) x 6N in the merge sort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I understand that each layer requires a maximum of 6N operations to merge. I also understand that we can calculate how many layers there are via log2 N, so if we had an array of length 4, then we split this twice to get arrays of length 1. The layers of length 1 would require a max total of 24 operations to form layers of length 2, and these would require 24 operations to merge into the next etc. That leaves the question of where the plus 1 comes from in this equation, since no merging occurs in the very final layer, which is just our output and for instance in my example, merging occurs only twice (from arrays of length 1 to arrays of length 2, then arrays of length 2 to arrays of length 4)

Comment: What is an "operation?"  There's no way to  answer your question without knowing the model of computation or algorithm you're assuming,

Comment: Sorry I meant 6n primitive operations. This was from the standford coursera course on algorithms, based on the book "algorithms illuminated" by Tim Roughgarden. This formula was given for the mergesort algorithm. His definition of primitive operation is loosely defined as "performing a simple task (like adding, comparing, or
copying) while touching a small number of simple variables (like 32-bit integers)" (pg.25 chp 1.5) Sorry if the question was unclear I have just started learning and assumed the way he presented the merge sort algorithm was the universal way that it was understood.

Comment: That should probably be ceiling(log2(n)).